# Finding groups with multiple facets

Tags: solr, facet

I'm trying to figure out if something is possible with SOLR 4.0.

I have a bunch of documents I have indexed, which I can search on with success. What I am trying to figure out is how to find groups of documents where the GROUP has a particular set of facets.

For example, lets say the documents I have is a list of books with 
Author, Type (Fiction or Non-Fiction), Title and Synopsis as the schema.

What I would like to be able to do is group by Author and find all Authors that write both Fiction and Non-Fiction books. I know how to get the group, and I set up the facets to show group counts rather than document counts. I just can't figure out if it possible to do a fq search and find groups that have the facets required.